# Definition of a multiple integral without hyperrectangles?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Could you define multiple integrals in a formally satisfactory manner without resorting to hyperrectangles and limits of integral sums?

I just don't like that definition for no serious objective reason, so I'm just curious if there's a more elegant way to define it.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a triple integral or higher?

Comment: yes, a general definition for integral of $n$ variables